# For Loop Custom Fields

Tags: php

i need help for this task.

i need a for loop who picks the closest duration

sample we have a duration with 120 seconds the 120 seconds are on every calculation divided by 8
so here is an example

120 Duration

Here are the 8 closest values
15
30
45
60
75
90
105
120

How i can realize this i have all tested

```
<?php
$count = 1;
$duration = 120;
$temp = 0;
for ($x = 1; $x < 120; $x++) {
    #$j = $x / 8;
    $temp = $x / 8;
    echo '<pre>' . ($temp) . '</pre>';

    if ($count == 8) {
        break;
    }
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to find a number, which is 15 or a number which is a multitude of 15, closest to duration? So if duration is 130 you want to find 135 and if it is 125 you want to find 120?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear and the provided code doesn't go from 1->120 since you break it after 8 iterations.
To get the values 15 30 45 60 75 90 105 120 from the base 120 you would need something like this:

```
$result = array();
$duration = 120; //the duration in seconds as provided in the example
$divider = 8; //the divider 8 as provided by the example

for ($i = 1; $i <= $divider; $i++) {
    //This will give 1* 120/8 = 15 for the first run
    //2* 120/8 = 30 for the second and so on
    $result[] = (int) $i * $duration / $divider;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your entire loop is totally redundant. Why not just this:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; i < 8; ++$i)
{
   echo '<pre>' . (15 * ($i+1)) . '</pre>';
}
?>
```

You can use `$i` directly as a counter in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
  $result[] = (int) ($duration / 8) * $i;
}
```

?

Comment: this will give quadratic samples, no? (15, 17, 20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 120)

Answer (score 1):

would the following work?

```
function sample($max, $count) {
  $samples = array();
  for($i = 1; $i <= $count; ++i) {
    $samples[] = (int)($max / $count * $i);
  }
  return $samples;
}
```